# mutt + offlineimap and only few folder offline

Tags: email, debian, mutt, debian-stretch

I have been trying to understand `offlineimap` with `mutt` configuration but I probably do not. In the end, I realised that what i need is to have offline only e.b. `Inbox` and `Sent`. That configuration one can find on internet but I also need to be able to access the other folders in `mutt` but without having to download them offline.

E.g.
I want all mails in `Inbox` to be downloaded offline to the computer and `mutt` accessing them from the local repository. But I also need to access folder `Inbox/SomeMore` but without having to reconfigure `mutt` and `offlineimap` and most importantly without donwloading the whole content of that folder to the computer.

Is this doable? And exactly how?

Answer (score 0):

`offlineimap`'s job is to download mails and make them available in offline situations. There is no way to temporary download the content of some mail folders. It might be possible to go for a hacky solution. Specify the folders you don't want to sync with the `folderfilter` option and additionally set up mutt to access the other IMAP folders.

You can specify a [folder filter](http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/nametrans.html) that excludes specific folders. Instead of adding the subfolder's name to the list it might be even possible to exclude it like this `INBOX/foo` (in case of having multiple folders with the same name):

```
folderfilter = lambda folder: folder in ['INBOX', 'Sent', 'Drafts', 'Junk', 'foo', ...]
```

**PS:** If folderfilter is not specified at all, ALL remote folders will be synchronized.